# Upgrade 2 Ghost blogs on same server, 1 quits immediately when run as a service

Tags: nginx, service, node.js, 502-error, ghost-blog

I have 2 Ghost blogs on a Digital Ocean server running:

- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
- Nginx 1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
- Node v0.12.7

I used the [instructions provided by Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-multiple-ghost-blogs-on-one-vps-using-nginx-server-blocks) to set up the blogs, and they have worked fine and survived upgrades before.

Last night, I upgraded blog #1 from Ghost v0.6.0 to 0.7.0 and experienced no problems. After upgrading I ran `service ghost-{blog1} restart` and it came online with pomp and triumph.

I immediately attempted to upgrade blog #2 following the same steps, but when I opened it in my browser after restarting the service, I got the "502 Bad Gateway" error.

I found that npm failed to install SQLite3 correctly, and fixed that. Now, I can start the blog successfully by running `npm start --production`. The terminal shows that Ghost is running and intercepting requests, and I can use the site and blogging app in my browser.

But when I run `service ghost-{blog2} start`, it continues to fail without presenting a terminal error. I get the following message:

```
ghost-{blog2} start/running, process 1693
```

But I still see the "502 Bad Gateway" error in my browser.

Edit: I changed my startup script to run `npm start --production > ghost-{blog2}.log` instead of `npm start --production`, and I can see that Ghost starts up, and then quits immediately without error:

```
> ghost@0.7.0 start /var/www/{blog2}/ghost
> node index
```

That's all that is in the log, even after hitting the page a few times. Nginx logs the requests, but Ghost doesn't.

By contrast, when I start the blog by running `npm start --production > ghost-{blog2}.log` from the terminal, the log continues thus:

```
> ghost@0.7.0 start /var/www/{blog2}/ghost
> node index

Migrations: Up to date at version 004
Ghost is running in production...
Your blog is now available on http://{blog2}
Ctrl+C to shut down
{{Requests}}
```

Can anyone suggest steps I can take to troubleshoot this?

Edit: Here are the relevant configuration details for each blog.

### Blog #1: This is the one that works

#### /var/www/{blog1}/config.js

```
production: {
    url: 'http://{blog1}',
    mail: {},
    database: {
        client: 'sqlite3',
        connection: {
            filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost.db')
        },
        debug: false
    },

    server: {
        // Host to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        // Port to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`, for iisnode set this to `process.env.PORT`
        port: '2369'
    }
},
```

#### /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/{blog1}

```
    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name {blog1};

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        client_max_body_size 10G;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:2369;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_buffering off;
        }
    }
```

#### /etc/init/ghost-{blog1}.conf

```
    # ghost-{blog1}

    start on startup

    script
        cd /var/www/{blog1}
        npm start --production
    end script
```

### Blog #2: This one works when I start using npm start --production, but fails when I start as a service

#### /var/www/{blog2}/ghost/config.js

```
production: {
    url: 'http://{blog2}',
    mail: {},
    database: {
        client: 'sqlite3',
        connection: {
            filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost.db')
        },
        debug: false
    },

    server: {
        // Host to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        // Port to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`, for iisnode set this to `process.env.PORT`
        port: '2777'
    }
},
```

### /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/{blog2}

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        server_name {blog2};

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        client_max_body_size 10G;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:2777;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_buffering off;
        }
    }
```

#### /etc/init/ghost-{blog2}.conf

```
    # ghost-{blog2}

    start on startup

    script
        cd /var/www/{blog2}/ghost
        npm start --production > ghost-{blog2}.log
    end script
```

Comment: What are the config files of both blogs (with SMTP or DB credentials censored) ?

Comment: Thank you, @AndréBorie—I've updated the post to include the relevant details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem!

**The answer was to *downgrade* Node.js to version 0.10.40.** When I wrote the above, I was running node vv0.12.7.

[Ghost's install documentation](http://support.ghost.org/installation/) says it supports v0.12.x, but when looking at it again today, I noticed that it recommends v0.10.40.

It's not clear to me at all why this solves the problem, but I'll take it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up removing node_modules for ghost and then reinstalled everything.

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean
npm install --production
```

Sqlite3 was not install properly, so I had to reinstall that as well.
**This deleted my database, but I had a backup.**

```
npm install sqlite3
```

After restarting the services everything was working again.

```
service nginx restart && service ghost restart
```

Comment: Thanks for your report! I had to do this too, and like I said, for blog #1 it worked: I can run it via the service start command and the blog appears online without a hitch. Followed the same steps with blog #2 on the same server, and this does not fix the issue.